# Is sprintf(b, "%") defined?

Tags: c++, c

I have encountered some code doing this:

```
double a(30.0);
char buff[30];
sprintf(buff , "%.4f%", a);
std::cout << std::string(buff) << "!\n";
```

Basically I was wondering about the trailing `%`, is `sprintf()` defining what would happen if nothing follows a `%` ?

Comment: I'd say you've got Undefined Behavior there, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: The only character that can follow `%` that is not a valid format specifier is another `%`.

Comment: Ultimately a valid specifier is required except in one case. There are optional amenities (flags, sizes, precision, etc), but eventually a valid specifier must be provided, *except* as @WeatherVane said: consecutive `%`. That this `%` appears at the end of string is irrelevant; it's not valid and per the standard leads to UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it leads to undefined behaviour.

C11 Section 7.21.6.1 paragraph 4 says:

> After the %, the following appear in sequence:
> [...]
> — A *conversion specifier* character that specifies the type of conversion to be applied.

Later, paragraph 9 says:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

In your example, the percent sign is not followed by a conversion specifier, which I take to imply the specification is invalid, thus leading to undefined behaviour.

Comment: In case anyone cares, the relevant section in C99 is §7.19.6.1-p9

Answer (score 2):

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf the behaviour is undefined:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.